# DD-WRT / Ubuntu DHCP / SQUID Transparent Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, squid, dd-wrt

Trying to segregate WLAN clients based on VLAN SSID, but I can't use multiple ports on DD-WRT router.  AP is on second floor with only one drop going to basement where my SQUID/DHCPD server is.  If I had a second drop, I could do two VLANs and use DHCPD's multihome capability, pointing clients on SSID1 directly to internet while those on SSID2 have to go through proxy server via DHCPD's ROUTER directive.  I can't filter by MAC address due to different users on same machines.  User A gets full while user B gets pushed through a transparent proxy no matter what device they're on.  Additionally, both users need full local network access.

Is there a way to do this with DD-WRT and iptables, or am I stuck running a second drop?

Comment: Your question isn't making a lot of sense to me.  I don't understand how your questions about SSIDs would be in any way useful (machines join WLANs, not users) since apparently users will be sharing computers.  Since your question isn't making a lot of sense a the moment, I think you may need to step back and describe what you [actually need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would like to point everyone who connects to one SSID through a transparent proxy (SQUID/SQUIDguard) for content filtering while those who connect to a different SSID (on the same DD-WRT router) do not get filtered.  DHCPD allows different configurations based on what interface the request comes in on.  DD-WRT allows physical segregation using virtual SSIDs.  SSID1 can be directed through physical port 1, SSID2 through port 2.

Comment: On the DHCPD server, I can write directives saying requests on eth0 do not use the proxy while requests on eth1 DO use the proxy.  This works fine using two cables.  The problem is that I need to migrate this out of the lab into production where there is only one network drop between the router and the dhcp server.  I was asking if anyone knew of a way to do this logically via iptables or some other method.
Also, I'm pretty sure wireless connections in Windows are configured at the user level.  User A does not necessarily have to connect to the same AP as User B on the same machine.